# 入れ子にしたフラグメントからActivityを操作する

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

Activityのフラグメントに`FragmentTabHost`を使ってリストフラグメントを入れ子にしたのですが､その入れ子にされたリストフラグメントから､Activityに情報を伝えることはできますか?  できるのであればその方法を教えて頂ければ嬉しいです｡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

子供の`ListFragment`の`getActivity()`を呼ぶと、FragmentがAttachされている`Activity`が取得できます。

Comment: @fkm様
回答ありがとうございます｡ では､入れ子にされたリストフラグメントで宣言したインタフェースを親の親のアクティビティに実装して呼び出すことができるのですか?

Comment: よい設計であるかは考える必要がありますが、呼べます。

Comment: @fkm様 お返事遅くなりましてすみません｡  では､その方針でやってみます｡  ありがとうございました｡